# IIS 7 to IIS 6 - difference in OS

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, configuration, iis-6

Our windows dev machines have Windows 7 OS and IIS 7. If we do development in this environment, and production environment is W 2003 and IIS 6. What options do I have to move my development to production efficiently. Upgrading Production from 2003 to 2008 or later is not an option. Downgrading dev machines from windows 7 is also not a good idea. Thanks for the comments and feedback.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the application pool in IIS 7 to run in classic mode, that makes it handle request as it did in IIS 6.

Comment: You mean while developing our application on IIS 7/Windows 7 - if we run it in classic mode, it can be easily portable to IIS 6?

Comment: @Ohark: Yes. Running it in classic mode removes a long list of small differences in how the requests are handled, so it minimises the risk for complications when you deploy it on IIS 6.